# python print vs __str__?

Tags: python, python-2.7

can anyone enlighten me on the differences between `print sth` and `print str(sth)` ?

E.g. in the example from the [official documentation for sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects), one can currently see the following code that creates a database and then uses a factory class to wrap data extracted from there:

(1) Create a database:

```
# I am using CPython 2.7, but I suppose 2.6 will be Ok as well
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''create table stocks
(date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
c.execute("""insert into stocks values ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)""")
conn.commit()

c.close()
```

(2) Now using the `Row` factory to produce some objects:

```
>>> conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
>>> c = conn.cursor()

>>> c.execute('select * from stocks')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f4e7dd8fa80>
>>> r = c.fetchone()
>>> type(r)
<type 'sqlite3.Row'>
>>> r
(u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14)
```

As you see, we can type `r`, or `print r` to get this nice representation of the row object.

But what is not shown above, it is that `print str(r)` will give you something different -- something more like:

```
<sqlite3.Row object at 0x7f4e7dd8abcd>
```

So I wonder if someone well-acquainted with CPython implementation can explain what print does to obtain this kind of representation from an object that does not support `__str__` ?

Or I guess an alternative question would be -- in the case when the above expressions give different results -- how I can obtain a string equivalent to the one that would be printed with simple `print obj` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can printing an object result in different output than both str() and repr()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920284/how-can-printing-an-object-result-in-different-output-than-both-str-and-repr)

Comment: @CiroSantilli华涌低端人口六四事件法轮功 : good point. Although -- though I am certainly biased -- I like my answer better. PS: ["how I learned to stop worrying and love the dupes"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: Copy your answer there, modify one line to avoid dupe answer moderators, and let's close this :-)

Answer (score 7):

While I was writing this and looking for some references, I have actually found the most part of the answer:

1. the C implementation for a Python object may implement [PyObject_Print()](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Print) function, which defines the way the object will be printed to a file, including `stdout`;
2. So to get that representation, one should probably use the [cStringIO](http://pymotw.com/2/StringIO/index.html#module-cStringIO) module (didn't try that yet, but supposedly this should work).

Nevertheless, I will leave this question here in a hope that someone may find it useful -- or provide a better answer.

**Upd.** A `cStringIO` example:

```
import cStringIO as C; s = C.StringIO(); print >>s, r, ; s.getvalue()
```

-- the last comma helps to get rid of the newline character(s) [ what I suppose depends on the platform ]

PS. Couple of somewhat related questions here on SO:
  -- [**"Python print isn't using __repr__, __unicode__ or __str__ for unicode subclass?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687676/python-print-isnt-using-repr-unicode-or-str-for-unicode-subclass)
  -- [**"Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

( For example, the first question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15687898/558008) answer has this nice [link](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2145593d108d/Objects/fileobject.c) to the code of [PyFile_WriteObject()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2145593d108d/Objects/fileobject.c#l2442) . )

PPS. In py3k, this discrepancy [seems to be gone completely](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/fileobject.c#l140).

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Both methods will return a string representing the object, but:

- `__repr__` *should* return a valid Python expresion or something like `<....>` if it can't produce that
- `__str__` *could* return a more *user friendly* string

Formally, `print sth` if the same as `print repr(sth)`:

```
>>> class C:
...   def __str__(self):
...     return "__str__"
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "__repr__"
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> c
__repr__
>>> print c
__str__
>>> `c`
'__repr__'
>>> repr(c)
'__repr__'
>>> str(c)
'__str__'
```

Concerning the `print` statement, [If an object is not a string, it is first converted to a string using the rules for string conversions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) and concerning *string conversion rules* : [The built-in function repr() performs exactly the same conversion in its argument as enclosing it in parentheses and reverse quotes does. The built-in function str() performs a similar but more user-friendly conversion.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#string-conversions)

---

**EDIT:** Concerning the specific case cited as an example, it appears that [at C-level](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e9d0fb934b46/Modules/_sqlite/row.c#l215) `sqlite3.row` defines [PyTypeObject.tp_print](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_print) as a pointer to a custom printing function that forwards to `PyTuple_Type.tp_print`. In the same time, [tp_str](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_str) and [tp_repr](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_repr) are left undefined -- an so will fallback to the default object print behavior as observed.

As a conclusion, with python 2.x, `print(obj)`, `print(str(obj))` and `print(repr(obj))` have the potential to produce three different results.

This discrepancy seems to have been lifted in 3.x as the print *statement* became a normal *function*.

```
# In Python 3.3:
>>> print(r)
<sqlite3.Row object at 0x7f4cedfbffd0>
>>> print(repr(r))
<sqlite3.Row object at 0x7f4cedfbffd0>
>>> print(str(r))
<sqlite3.Row object at 0x7f4cedfbffd0>
```

---

**EDIT2:** Still concerning the specific case of `sqlite3.Row`, it appears that a row could be converted to a tuple. I have tested it both with Python 2.6 and 3.3.

Python 2.6:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) \n[GCC 4.4.5]'
>>> type(r)
<type 'sqlite3.Row'>
>>> r
(u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100.0, 35.140000000000001)
>>> tuple(r)
(u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100.0, 35.140000000000001)
>>> repr(tuple(r))
"(u'2006-01-05', u'BUY', u'RHAT', 100.0, 35.140000000000001)"
```

Python 3.3:

```
>>> sys.version
'3.3.1 (default, May 28 2013, 18:34:21) \n[GCC 4.4.5]'
>>> type(r)
<type 'sqlite3.Row'>
>>> r
<sqlite3.Row object at 0x7f4cedfbffd0>
>>> tuple(r)
('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14)
>>> repr(tuple(r))
"('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14)"
```

Comment: "Formally, `print sth` if the same as `print str(sth)`" (there is an obvious typo in your text, 'str' <-> 'repr')

That's exactly what was my understanding of the subject before I have noticed that e.g. for the code from the question, neither the `str()` nor the `repr()` functions won't produce the same result as `c = cStringIO.StringIO(); print >>c ... ; c.getvalue()`

Comment: As you noticed the `PyObject_Print()` function allow native objects to implement their own _print behavior_ without relying on repr/str. My opinion is that it is somewhat a bad idea since it does not allow one to easily get that value back in a variable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I tend to agree. But my question was more about how things are implemented than on how they should have been (and, repeat, that was a bit of a surprise, as I also thought `print` and `print str` are more or less equivalent).

Comment: Having tested it, this behavior has been removed in Python 3.3 (presumably any Python 3.x). `print(r)` display the same thing as `print(repr(r))`. This is probably due to the fact that `print` is now a function an no longer a special language construct.

Comment: I absolutely agree that ["there should be .. preferably one way to do it"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), although -- as a side note -- the print statement is the thing I will be missing the most in py3k, and I can not understand why this _function_ can not also be a _statement_ as well. But that's a completely different thing, I guess.

Comment: If `>>s` causes output to go to `s` rather than `stdout`, would `<<s` cause input to come from `s` rather than `stdin`?

Comment: @ジョージ Personally, I find `print()` a lot easier to work with than `print`. Here's the rationale for why the statement version was removed, by the way: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/#rationale

Comment: @JAB 
I think it is a `print` thing, not a C++ - alike general convention; besides, I guess it was removed in Python 3.*

Comment: @JAB Basically, they want me to enter two extra characters every time I'm debugging something, and it was not like that before Ж:-)

Comment: @ジョージ Indeed, the current equivalent would be `print(*stringargs, file=s)`. And it's not two extra, it's only one (or none if you're using a text editor that supports automatic insertion of closing parentheses/braces/brackets/etc.). ...I'm not sure why the PEP says there's no equivalent to the old `softspace` feature, either. doesn't `print('s', end='')` perform a similar purpose?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: 
I think it should be `print(str(r))`, not `print(repr(r))` ; ( I guess this is an unintentional typo, but I'll leave this comment for those who'd be reading that later -- just in an attempt to avoid some confusion )

Comment: Not sure this is your question, but all the magic regarding _pretty formatting_ of `sqlite3.row` while using `print` happens here I think: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e9d0fb934b46/Modules/_sqlite/row.c#l162

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: yep, and then it is filled as an entry in the PyTypeObject structure: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e9d0fb934b46/Modules/_sqlite/row.c#l215 ;  

as for the code for printing of the object in 3.* -- it seems that now it is [either `str()` or `repr()`, depending on the flags](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/fileobject.c#l140) ( I didn't find easily any Python docs specifying how to control these flags from Python, so I assume it is always `str()` or `repr()` by default )

Comment: @ジョージ According to the doc, on 2.7, [Py_PRINT_RAW is the only acceptable flag](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_print) while calling `PyTypeObject.tp_print`.  Amusing enough, in 3.x `PyFile_WriteObject` has the [same restriction](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.5/c-api/file.html#PyFile_WriteObject). I can't see how [the corresponding test](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/fileobject.c#l140) could fail? Obviously, it if does (does it?), there are other allowed flags...

Comment: ... at least, `Py_PRINT_RAW`is the only _Py_PRINT_ flag defined in Include/object.h: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c8212fca8747/Include/object.h#l579 Anyway, I don't think you have the opportunity to control this flag from Python -- except by writing your own C wrapper especially for that purpose. Seems lots of trouble whereas on 2.X the [extended form of the print statement `print ... >>`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) should work well enough...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: I think there are just two possibilities for this flag -- either to exist or to be omitted (the latter would be the `else` clause at line 144 ), but it is interesting that the possibility is still there -- I assume it may exist e.g. to support the case where [Container’s __str__ uses contained objects’ __repr__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/558008).

Comment: @ジョージ That is correct. I didn't read the doc with enough attention :(. The Py_PRINT_RAW _bit_ may either be set or clear => two possibilities.  It would be interesting to trace back the code is order to see when `tp_print` is called with that bit set, and when it is called with that bit clear.

Comment: @ジョージ Please take a look at EDIT2 in my answer ;) May that should be what you were searching at first?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: For this case, this is indeed very much cleaner than the `cStringIO` thing )

Comment: Please put clarifying inofrmation into the answer or the question as appropriate. Comments are hard to follow once they get so big.